# Interface with method type depending on implementing class

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am writing an interface that has a method that is supposed to return a list of objects. The objects in the list will depend on the implementing class.

For Example:

```
interface IPlayMovie
{
   List<MoviePlayer> RetrievePlayersByMovie();
}
```

Is it possible to have a method where the return type of the list depends on the "MoviePlayer" (or class) that implements this interface? If so, how?

Note: The classes implementing this interface are not necessarily subclasses, and do not have similar enough object structures to be put into a family.

Comment: Interface can't contain the `static` keyword, `public` as well.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong... but, ¿public inside an interface member? and.. ¿static? What did I miss?

Comment: Side note: consider editing title of the post to be more precise... I read title as asking about [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but the question seem to be about basic generic interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called generic interface, e.g.:

```
interface IDataProvider<T>
{
    List<T> Retrieve();
}

class MoviePlayerProvider : IDataProvider<MoviePlayer>
{
    public List<MoviePlayer> Retrieve() { }
}
```

Comment: I'd just return `ICollection<T>` rather than its concrete implementation of `List<T>`

Comment: or IList<T> if the index is important